# Is it possible to generate .watchface for apple watch, without iphone's default watch app or apple watch itself?

Tags: swift, xcode, watch, watchface

I want to generate a .watchface file from my xcode project. Is there any way to create .watchface file from outside of the default Watch app?

I have found a website [Facer](https://www.facer.io/creator), where they are offering customizing options and generating .watchface from their website. What approach they are following?

Comment: did you find any solution  for this

Answer (score 3):

name.watchface -> name.zip
Unzip it and make it into that structure
Create watchface file programmatically and execute CLKWatchFaceLibrary().addWatchFace API

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).